# Stacking Free Monads

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, free-monad, scala-cats

I'm learning about the Free monads, and I've put together a simple example in Scala where I use them to define two domain specific languages.

The first monad deals with the side effects of a repository. I have implemented an interpreter that uses the state monad to manage the state, but in a real program I'd use a database.

The second monad deals with IO.

```scala
import cats.data.State
import cats.{Id, ~>}
import cats.free.Free
import cats.free.Free.liftF

final case class Todo(title: String, body: String)
def represent(todo: Todo) = s"${todo.title}: ${todo.body}"


sealed trait CRUDActionA[T]
final case class Find(key: String) extends CRUDActionA[Option[Todo]]
final case class Add(data: Todo) extends CRUDActionA[Unit]

type CRUDAction[T] = Free[CRUDActionA, T]
def find(key: String): CRUDAction[Option[Todo]] = liftF[CRUDActionA, Option[Todo]](Find(key))
def add(data: Todo): CRUDAction[Unit] = liftF[CRUDActionA, Unit](Add(data))

type TodosState[A] = State[List[Todo], A]
val repository: CRUDActionA ~> TodosState = new (CRUDActionA ~> TodosState) {
  def apply[T](fa: CRUDActionA[T]): TodosState[T] = fa match {
    case Add(todo)   => State.modify(todos => todos :+ todo)
    case Find(title) => State.inspect(todos => todos find (_.title == title))
  }
}


sealed trait IOActionA[T]
final case class Out(str: String) extends IOActionA[Unit]

type IOAction[T] = Free[IOActionA, T]
def out(str: String): IOAction[Unit] = liftF[IOActionA, Unit](Out(str))

val io: IOActionA ~> Id = new (IOActionA ~> Id) {
  override def apply[A](fa: IOActionA[A]): Id[A] = fa match {
    case Out(todo) => println(todo)
  }
}
```

Then, I can put together these two "programs"

```scala
def addNewTodo: Free[CRUDActionA, Option[Todo]] = for {
  _ <- add(Todo(title = "Must do", body = "Must do something"))
  todo <- find("Must do")
} yield todo

def outProgram(todo: Todo): IOAction[Unit] = for {
  _ <- out(represent(todo))
} yield ()
```

And run them doing

```scala
val (_, mayBeTodo) = (addNewTodo foldMap repository run List()).value
outProgram(mayBeTodo.get).foldMap(io)
```

I understand this is far from ideal, and I'd like to write a program as and an interpreter that supports:

```scala
def fullProgram = for {
  _ <- add(Todo(title = "Must do", body = "Must do something"))
  todo <- find("Must do")     // This is an option!!!
  _ <- out(represent(todo))   // But represent expects a Todo
} yield ()
```

So the questions are:

1. How can I stack the two monads together into a "fullProgram"
2. How can I compose the two interpreters into a new interpreter?
3. How do I deal with the Option[Todo] returned by `find`, and then passed to
   `represent`

Comment: there're some projects trying to generate these things without writing boilerplate. for example FreeDSL -> https://github.com/ISCPIF/freedsl

Answer (score 1):

Answer to questions 1 & 2:

```
  type TodoApp[A] = Coproduct[IOActionA, CRUDActionA, A]


  class CRUDActions[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[CRUDActionA, F]) {
    def find(key: String): Free[F, Option[Todo]] = Free.inject[CRUDActionA, F](Find(key))
    def add(data: Todo): Free[F, Unit] = Free.inject[CRUDActionA, F](Add(data))
  }

  object CRUDActions {
    implicit def crudActions[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[CRUDActionA, F]): CRUDActions[F] = new CRUDActions[F]
  }

  class IOActions[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[IOActionA, F]) {
    def out(str: String): Free[F, Unit] = Free.inject[IOActionA, F](Out(str))
  }

  object IOActions {
    implicit def ioActions[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[IOActionA, F]): IOActions[F] = new IOActions[F]
  }

  def fullProgram(implicit C : CRUDActions[TodoApp], I : IOActions[TodoApp]): Free[TodoApp, Unit] = {
    for {
      _    <- C.add(Todo(title = "Must do", body = "Must do something"))
      todo <- C.find("Must do")
      _    <- I.out(represent(todo.get))
    } yield ()
  }

  object ConsoleCatsInterpreter extends (IOActionA ~> Id) {
    def apply[A](i: IOActionA[A]) = i match {
      case Out(prompt) => println(prompt).asInstanceOf[A]
    }
  }

  object MutableListCrudInterpreter extends (CRUDActionA ~> Id) {
    val data = new ListBuffer[Todo]

    override def apply[A](fa: CRUDActionA[A]): Id[A] = fa match {
      case Add(todo)   => data.append(todo).asInstanceOf[A]
      case Find(title) => data.find( _.title == title).asInstanceOf[A]
    }
  }

  val interpreter: TodoApp ~> Id = ConsoleCatsInterpreter or MutableListCrudInterpreter

  fullProgram.foldMap(interpreter)
```